# Подмена Assembly

Tags: c#

Возможно ли подменить Assembly?

Ситуация такова:

При подключение к сети на клиент передаеться файл в виде байтов - далее выполняется функция

```
if (numArray != null && numArray.Length != 0 && Method.Initialize(Assembly.Load(numArray)))
```

Возможно ли подменить каким нибудь образом Эту dll на свою?
Менять dll с данным кодом нет смысла,так как она проверяться на различия с копией на сервере - ту, что хочу заменить не проверяется

Comment: Проверяли `GUID`?

Comment: @Birdy разве GUID меняется при изменение через reflector?

Comment: да, возможно, клиент может подменить numArray на любой другой по содержанию numArray.

Comment: @PashaPash можете подсказать как примерно это сделать?Если что numArray приходит с сервера - ну или подскажите в какую сторону копать

Comment: @Gapsy201 берете клиентский exe, разбираете его ildasm-ом, меняете код выше на любой другой (например, на подгрузку нужной вам сборки с диска), собираете обратно из il в exe.

Comment: @PashaPash этот код в dll - эта dll при запуске проверяется на изменение с dll на сервере.Если изменение были - нерабочее все становиться

Comment: @Gapsy201 эта dll разбирается, меняется код, собирается обратно. код, который отправляет dll на сервер на проверку, меняется так, чтобы отправлять оригинальную неизмененную dll, которая просто лежит в файле.

Comment: @Gapsy201 достаточно очевидно, что можно поменять клиента так, чтобы он вел себя как оригинальный, слал те же данные, но при этом делал все, что угодно :)

Comment: @PashaPash dll подписана Confused 1.0 обфускатором - de4dot не берет

Comment: @Gapsy201 ну т.е. ваш вопрос сводится к "можно ли подправить код, по которому прошлись каким-то конкретным обфускатором" - да, можно. Для того же опенсорсового бесплатного Confuser-а есть точно такой же опенсорсовый бесплатный деобфускатор. Любой альтернативный/платный обфускатор тоже ломается, вопрос всегда в сложности/цене.

Comment: @PashaPash кроме de4dot деобфускаторов вроде нет нормальных

Comment: @Gapsy201 конкретно под confuser гуглится https://github.com/CodeShark-Dev/NoFuserEx и https://github.com/ubbelol/ConfuserDeobfuscator. Не знаю, насколько они рабочие. Суть комментария выше от этого не меняется - любая "защита" на клиентской части ломается. "Защита" - потому что любая обфускация - это security through obscurity. Т.е. ее не взламывают ровно до тех пор, пока ваш софт не станет кому-нибудь нужным.

Answer (score 0):

```
numArray = File.ReadAllBytes("xxx.dll"));
if (numArray != null && numArray.Length != 0 && Method.Initialize(Assembly.Load(numArray)))
```